Strange monitor issue: White cloudy line across top of monitor
I have this strange white wavy cloudy line on my monitor. its been there for many months and has changed over time. At first it was near the top bezel and now has moved down and become more bright.
The shape has changed as well: The top part where it first appeared is normal again. The monitor is Dell S2716DG 5 year old. Almost always on with pictures for screensaver. Any idea what it is and how to remedy it?


If you take a screenshot (not a picture of the screen), does the line show up? It probably does not, but you should check that. If it does not show up, the issue is with the screen physically, and you will need to service the screen or, more likely, replace it. If the line shows up in a screenshot, this is a software issue and you'll want to start by updating drivers and firmware across your system.

Or separation of layers.

this does look like moisture ingress like one would see on artwork under glass. the fitment at the top edge is poor (you can see light leak from the panel at three locations) this is where the moisture is entering. probably condensation or humidity.

Thanks all for your comments. It was very insightful. Time to buy a new one. I am not aware of water coming in from somewhere and humidity is controlled. Bummer
